# UIWebview load the pages with desktop version view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, loading

I load the webpages with UIWebView using

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

it's work well but my problem is it always load with desktop version view.
I don't want to load desktop version view. Please help me . I will appreciate you all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with UIWebView, your website needs to detect that the user-agent is a mobile device and forward to your mobile version.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply.
But the website is not belong to me, it can be any websites.
If i use request method, it's ok . it can show mobile view. But if i use above methods it show as desktop view.